# Reading an array of elements with readf in D

Tags: d

Is it possible to read an array (of given length) of elements using `readf` in D, without looping?

And is it possible if the length is not known?

I tried using the same syntax used for formatted writing, `%(%d %)`, but it does not work.

EDIT: More generally, is `readf` capable of using the same formats for `writef`?

Comment: Also jamming code? =)

Comment: Yeah! :) I took the occasion to learn D, eheh

Comment: It does pretty well... Much better than C++, mainly because of std.algorithm. Couldn't get to work a BigInt impl for C's 2nd large set though.

Comment: Sry for OT btw, I don't know either how to do that. I'm doing `readln().strip().split().map!(to!size_t)()` most of the time.

Comment: Oh, nice :) I am *really* new with D, and my approach until now was a simple `readf` in a loop :D

Comment: Having discovered array page (http://dlang.org/arrays.html) I also found a convenient copy syntax using `[]` on both l and r values.

Comment: Yeah you can.. but how does it help you to do readf? Or is it just that you want an array as output? If so, just append `.array()` from std.array to a range expression.

Comment: Actually it does not really help with that :P I still have to readln, split and convert :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently a bug ([Bugzilla 10060](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=10060)) that prevents this from working, but it does work for linewise reading.

```
foreach (line; stdin.byLine())
{
    int[] result;
    formattedRead(line, "%(%d,%)", &result);
    writeln(result);
}
```